# How can I install aggdraw after this error?

Tags: python, graphics, aggdraw

I am trying to install the aggdraw python library to create high quality graphics but I keep getting this error:

```
agg22/include/agg_array.h: In member function `agg::int8u*
```

What is the workaround for this? How can I install it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should follow the instructions in http://www.pocketuniverse.ca/archive/2008/december/11/pil-and-aggdraw/ to patch AGG rather than just have the compiler allow the 64-bit incompatible code to compile.

Here's one way you could do it in the shell:

```
cd /tmp
svn co http://svn.effbot.org/public/tags/aggdraw-1.2a3-20060212
cd aggdraw-1.2a3-20060212
patch -p0 <<EOF
Index: agg2/include/agg_array.h
===================================================================
--- agg2/include/agg_array.h    (revision 532)
+++ agg2/include/agg_array.h    (working copy)
@@ -520,7 +520,7 @@
                 int8u* ptr = m_buf_ptr;
                 if(alignment > 1)
                 {
-                    unsigned align = (alignment - unsigned(ptr) % alignment) % alignment;
+                    unsigned align = (alignment - (unsigned long)(ptr) % alignment) % alignment;
                     size += align;
                     ptr += align;
                     if(size <= m_rest)
EOF

python setup.py build_ext -i
python selftest.py
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: I made a gist here you can wget and execute, if you are maximally lazy: https://gist.github.com/jsundram/6022938

Answer (score 3):

(Yes I am answering my own question)

After searching a lot through the web I found that doing

```
export CFLAGS="-fpermissive"
```

before building the extension with `python setup.py build_ext -i` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Worked for me. Passed the selftest and installed ok (I had to set the env variable after `su`ing to root to install).